# indenting specific parts of output in bash

Tags: bash

say I have the following bash script that finds all error.logs  gives them a header and then tails 5 lines below it..

```
#!/bin/bash
for ERR in `find -name "error.log"`;
do
    echo -e "---- LOG: $ERR ----";
    tail -n 5 $ERR;
done;
```

I would like to have it output like so:

```
---- LOG: foo/error.log ----
    [error ....]
    [error ....]
---- LOG: foo/error.log ----
    [error ....]
    [error ....]
---- LOG: foo/error.log ----
    [error ....]
    [error ....]
```

where the `tail`'d section is indented some amount of characters (e.g. 4 or whatever a tab character is)

How would I indent that specific section out output?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pipe your tail command through sed:

```
tail -n 5 $ERR | sed -e 's/^/    /'
```

Comment: Also works with `cat`, and presumably anything else whose output can be piped through `sed`... this was just what I needed! :)

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways.  One might be to simply pipe through sed or awk and add some space.

```
cat syslog | sed -e 's/^/    /'
#
cat syslog | sed -e 's/^/\t/'
```